# Computing $\int^{4b}_0 {e^{-tx}\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{4bx-x^2}}{(2b-2c)^2+4cx}\biggr) dx}$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration, special-functions, approximation-theory, integral-transforms

I am a PhD student working on complex analysis. After integrating over a keyhole contour to obtain the inverse of a particular Laplace transform, I ended up with the following integral:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{4b}_0 e^{-tx}\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{4bx-x^2}}{(2b-2c)^2+4cx}\biggr) dx $$

where $b$, $c$ and $ t $  are positive constants. This integral corresponds to the linear segments of the contour, which has two branch points.

My current progress:

$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int^{4b}_0  e^{-tx}\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{(2b)^2-(x-2b)^2}}{(2b-2c)^2+4cx}\biggr) dx. $$

Using trigonometric substitution:  $ (x-2b) = 2b\sin z $

$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int e^{-t(\ 2b+2b\sin z)}\biggl(\frac{4b^2\cos^2 z}{(2b-2c)^2 + 8bc\ +4c(2b\sin z)}\biggr) dz. $$

Could someone please help me to continue or show me a different way to approach to the problem?

Comment: It might help to know what was the function whose inverse Laplace transform you started with.

Comment: for $c=b$ your integral evaluates to $\frac{1}{2} \pi  e^{-2 b t} [I_0(2 b t)+I_1(2 b t)]$ --- for $c\neq b$ a closed-form solution is not likely to be forthcoming.